# How to use multidimensional array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

What i want is:
Array-one (the product db array):

- Product id
- Cat name

Array-two (the category db array):

- cat id
- Cat name

if Array-one: cat name is equal to Array-two: cat name add all product ids under the cat id

```
  //this foreach is loop to products
  foreach($objects as $object) {

     //get cat name from product db
     $cat_name_product = $object['values']['17'];

        // this foreach is loop to cat db
        foreach($cat_db as $cat_object) {

           // get cat name from cat db
           $cat_name_cat_table = $cat_object['values'][2];

            // if cat from product DB is equal to cat name from cat DB
            if($cat_name_product == $cat_name_cat_table){

            $cat_name_product_id = $object['id'];
            $cat_name_db_id = $cat_object['id'];
             
            // Add products ids to a specfic row id from cat
              $cat_db_row[$cat_name_db_id][] =  $cat_name_product_id;
    
    
            }
         }
    }
```

Result array:

```
Array
(
    [45156381272] => Array
        (
            [0] => 44990952854
        )

    [45002415686] => Array
        (
            [0] => 45054787942
            [1] => 45056971448
            [2] => 45049917079
            [3] => 45056971449
        )

)
```

what i want:

```
Array
(
    [0] => (
          [cat_id] => 45156381272
          [product_ids] => Array
        (
            [0] => 44990952854
        )
)
    [1] =>      
          [cat_id] => 45156381272
          [product_ids] => Array
        (
        [0] => 45054787942
        [1] => 45056971448
        [2] => 45049917079
        [3] => 45056971449
        )

)
```

How do i do this?

Comment: Please share your input data - it's difficult to test an algorithm without the data structure you're running it on. Edit the question and add the result of `var_export` on your starting arrays.

Answer (score 0):

My code gets the desired result:

Input Data:

```
$arrayProducts = [["Cat_name" => 'cat example 1', "product_id" => 44990952854],
                ["Cat_name" => 'cat example 2', "product_id" => 44990952854],
                ["Cat_name" => 'cat example 2', "product_id" => 44990952854],
                ["Cat_name" => 'cat example 2', "product_id" => 44990952854],
                ["Cat_name" => 'cat example 2', "product_id" => 44990952854]];

$arrayCategories = [["cat_id" => 45156381272, "Cat_name" => 'cat example 1'],
                ["cat_id" => 45002415686, "Cat_name" => 'cat example 2']];
```

Code:

I iterate first the categories array and then (inner) the products arrays.

```
<?php

$resultArray = array();

foreach($arrayCategories as $key => $element2) {
    $resultArray[$key] = array("cat_id" => $element2["cat_id"], "products_ids" => array());

    foreach($arrayProducts as $element1) {
        if($element1["Cat_name"] == $element2["Cat_name"]) {
            $resultArray[$key]["products_ids"][] = $element1["product_id"];
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Output ($resultArray)

```
array ( 0 => array ( 'cat_id' => 45156381272, 'products_ids' => array ( 0 => 44990952854, ), ), 1 => array ( 'cat_id' => 45002415686, 'products_ids' => array ( 0 => 44990952854, 1 => 44990952854, 2 => 44990952854, 3 => 44990952854, ), ), );
```

Answer (score -1):

- *Keep* using the category ID as array index, while you are building the array. That is (IMHO) the most efficient way to accumulate the data under that ID - otherwise, you would have to *search* your array for the index of the item with the category ID of the current record all the time.
- Add another dimension below that, for the category ID, and the product IDs:
  `$cat_db_row[$cat_name_db_id]['cat_id']        = $cat_name_db_id;`
  `$cat_db_row[$cat_name_db_id]['product_ids'][] = $cat_name_product_id;`

  (Technically, that first line overwrites `$cat_db_row[$cat_name_db_id]['cat_id']` again and again - but since it is always with the same category ID value, that doesn’t matter. You could do a check whether `$cat_db_row[$cat_name_db_id]['cat_id']` is already set first, but that would have rather little point.)
- “Reset” the array keys afterwards, when you are done filling the array, using
  `$cat_db_row = array_values($cat_db_row);`
  This will throw away all the existing (top-level) array keys, and re-index the array numerically, starting at 0.